# Cannot make a condition to test a CSS style

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a condition to test an elements style attributes to position an element on or off the screen when the menu button is clicked. However, JavaScript will not detect the style. Here is my code:

```js
const menu = document.getElementById('menu')
menu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let nav = document.getElementById('navHolder');
  if (nav.style.right == `30rem`) {
    console.log('true')
  } else {
    console.log('false');
  }
})
```

```css
#navHolder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  z-index: 99;
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30rem;
}

#navBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: rgb(56, 55, 55);
  width: 95vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 98;
}
```

```html
<nav id='navBar'>
  <button id='menu'>
    <div id='menuText'>MENU</div>
  </button>
</nav>
<div id="navHolder">
  <div id='navBox'>
    <div class="navList" id="closeBox">X</div>
    <div class="navList" id="back">CLOSE</div>
    <div class="navList" id="home">HOME</div>
    <div class="navList" id="weightLoss">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `nav.style.right` target only inline element styles. Use `offset` instead.

Comment: Also, further to Pavel's comment, the distance would be reported in pixel-units, not rem; see the console in the [demo].

Comment: Or you could use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).  But again, this would report in px and not rem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work don't modify individual styling attributes of an element, simply toggle a class on the element you wish to affect; this class-name can be easily identified, added and removed; certainly more so than individual attribute changes.

For example:

```
// retrieve the button element to trigger the function:
const menu = document.getElementById('menu')

// using EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the anonymous
// function as the event-handler for the "click" event:
menu.addEventListener("click", function() {

  // retrieve the element to affect:
  let nav = document.getElementById('navHolder');

  // using the Element.classList API to toggle the 'offscreen'
  // class-name, if it's not present it will be added and vice-
  // versa:
  nav.classList.toggle('offscreen');
});
```

```js
const menu = document.getElementById('menu')

menu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let nav = document.getElementById('navHolder');
  nav.classList.toggle('offscreen');
});
```

```css
#navHolder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  z-index: 99;
  padding-bottom: 10vh;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30rem;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
}

#navHolder.offscreen {
  left: -30rem;
}

#navBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: rgb(56, 55, 55);
  width: 95vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav id='navBar'>
  <button id='menu'>
    <div id='menuText'>MENU</div>
  </button>
</nav>

<div id="navHolder">
  <div id='navBox'>
    <div class="navList" id="closeBox">X</div>
    <div class="navList" id="back">CLOSE</div>
    <div class="navList" id="home">HOME</div>
    <div class="navList" id="weightLoss">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dgcw1s9L/).

As mentioned in the comments to your question, lengths are typically reported from JavaScript in pixel units, therefore the `if (nav.style.right == '30rem')` could never be satisfied.

References:

- [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

you need use getComputedStyle(elem) and check property

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)